# Webpack 5 live reload

Tags: javascript, webpack, frontend

I updated webpack 4 to webpack 5, after which everything works, except for updating the browser (live reload) who can tell the reason? here is my config.

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  const { mode = 'development' } = argv;
  const isProd = mode === 'production';
  const isDev = mode === 'development';

  const getStyleLoaders = () => {
    return [isProd ? MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader : 'style-loader'];
  };
  return {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    mode: isProd ? 'production' : isDev && 'development',
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      filename: isDev ? 'script/script.js' : 'script/bundle-[hash:8].js',
      publicPath: '/',
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js'],
    },
    devServer: {
      contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
      publicPath: '/',
      open: true,
      watchContentBase: true,
      port: 8080,
    },
    devtool: isProd ? false : 'source-map',
  };
};
```

Answer (score 31):

You need to set `{target: 'web'}` in your Webpack config and also make sure to run your dev server like this: `webpack serve --mode development --env development`

Comment: Thanks Farid. I've been scouring the net and this was the only solution that worked for me.

Comment: Follow this issue for root cause and bug status: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/2758

Answer (score 2):

live reload will only work if the webpack bundle target is 'web',
so adding this line to webpack.config will make it work:

```
target: 'web'
```

Still, for the time this is being written, there is a bug in webpack-dev-server@3 that prevents live reload when target is an array that contains 'web':
https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/pull/3271

so you **can't** do that:

```
target: ['web', 'es5']
```

maybe one can use this workaround...

```
target: isProduction ? ['web', 'es5'] : 'web'
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution in the official documentation:
[devserverwatchfiles](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverwatchfiles)

Use **devServer.watchFiles**

> This option allows you to configure a list of globs/directories/files
> to watch for file changes.

For example:

*webpack.config.js*

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  devServer: {
    watchFiles: ['src/**/*'],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this could be related to your problem, but what version of webpack-cli are you using? Some are reporting this problem with *webpack-dev-server* due to *webpack-cli v4.0.0*:

[Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs' #2759](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/2759)

If you are having this problem, you could try downgrading *webpack-cli* to version: 3.3.0 (exact) and *webpack-dev-server* down to version: ^3.11.0.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with
webpack v5.39.0,
webpack-cli v4.7.2
webpack-dev-server v3.11.2
My way:

> npm install -D  webpack-dev-server@4.0.0-beta.0

`module.exports ={target:  "web"}` in config

and `"start": "webpack serve"` in package.json

Answer (score 0):

i had same error this is what fixed it:

## first

setting {target: 'web'} in the Webpack config

## second

under devServer config set:
publicPath: "/assets/",

## my config will:

```
    module.exports = {
    target: “web”,
    entry: {
    main: path.resolve(__dirname, “./src/index.js”)
    },
    output: {
    path: __dirname + “/dist/assets”,
    filename: “bundle.js”,
    publicPath: “assets”
    },
    mode: “development”,
    devServer: {
    open: true,
    contentBase: “./dist”,
    publicPath: “/assets/”,
    port: 3000,
    hot: false,
    watchContentBase: true
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. Here's how I solved it.

1. Add { target: 'web' }
2. Add { devServer: { hot: false, watchContentBase: true }}
3. Remove { devServer: { historyApiFallback: true }}
4. Result:

```js
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  target: 'web',
  entry: './src/app/main.ts',
  output: {
    path: paths.dist,
    filename: 'js/main.min.js?[fullhash]',
  },
  devServer: {
    open: true,
    overlay: true,
    contentBase: paths.dist,
    port: 8080,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    hot: false,
    watchContentBase: true,
  }
}
```

Start script:

```js
"scripts": {
  "dev": "webpack serve --mode development",
}
```

Start command:

```js
 npm run dev
```

My default browser open automatically on http://localhost:8080

When I edit my pug file, I see the result in browser.

Comment: `watchContentBase` is only available in webpack V4, cannot find it in the documentation anywhere and throws an error when I try to use it in the webpack.config.js

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue with webpack-dev-server v4.8.1 and this worked for me:-

```
devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    open:true,
    compress: true,
    port: 9000,
    hot:false
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

for webpack 5 you need to add static key to path where your app source code lies

```
devServer: {
    open: true,
    hot: true,
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue of live reload "not working": webpack would detect the changes to my code, but when it reloaded the page, the old version of the UI would still be displayed. I had this configuration for my dev server:

```
  devServer: {
    port: 8080,
    hot: true,
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, "public"), 
    },
    liveReload: true,
    watchFiles: [ path.join(__dirname, 'src/**/*') ]
  },
```

Then I set the 'cache' option to false (outside of the devServer options) and it worked:

```
cache: false,
```

For some reason the browser was keeping the cached version of my code even though I was making changes and it was reloading after I made those changes. However, I have another project with the exact same webpack config that works without needing cache set to false, so this may not be the best solution as it can cause slower build times in larger projects. It did the job though